# My view makes invisible after alter its height

Tags: android

```
 private boolean isOffersHidden = false; 



findViewById(R.id.imgHideOffers).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Animation animationOffers;

            if(!isOffersHidden){
                animationOffers = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.right_side);
                findViewById(R.id.lyOfffersContainer).setAnimation(animationOffers);
                findViewById(R.id.lyOfffersContainer).startAnimation(animationOffers);


                reduceHeight(findViewById(R.id.lyOfffersContainer));

                isOffersHidden = true;
            }else{
                animationOffers = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.appear_offers);
                findViewById(R.id.lyOfffersContainer).setAnimation(animationOffers);
                findViewById(R.id.lyOfffersContainer).startAnimation(animationOffers);

                increaseHeight(findViewById(R.id.lyOfffersContainer));

                isOffersHidden = false;
            }

        }

    });

  //Im using this piece of code to reduce my view height:

  private void reduceHeight(final View v) {

    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(v.getHeight(), 0);
    va.setDuration(1500);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    });

    va.start();
}


//Im using this code to increase my view height:

private void increaseHeight(final View v){

    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 220);
    va.setDuration(1500);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            v.requestLayout();
        }
    });

    va.start();
}
```

Everything is ok when I reduce the view height but when I try to increase the height again it becomes invisible:

*Normal view:*

[image]

***After reduce and increase the view height***

[image]

I hope you can understand my problem, Im not setting the view invisible programmatically, how can I fix this?

Comment: you should put the full code here. There's  no problem with your 2 functions.

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc Ok, I just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

yeap, the problem is your `onClick` function. The `reduceHeight` and `increaseHeight` take time to complement. In your code, if you click fast enough, 2 processes (reducing and increasing) run in parallel. That makes your `onClick` function unreliable. To fix it, you should cancel your animator before starting a new one such as:

```
ValueAnimator va = null; // make this animator global
private void reduceHeight(final View v) {
if(va != null) va.end(); // end the running animation; you should call this in the increaseHeight function as well. 
va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(v.getHeight(), 0);
va.setDuration(1500);
va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        v.getLayoutParams().height = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        v.requestLayout();
        //remember to set va = null when animation ends.
    }
});
va.start();
}
```

Comment: I think this helps that I can not quickly invoke the animations but it does not solve my problem, my view keeps appearing as if it were invisible

Comment: @JorgeRequez oh, I forgot to mention that you should try to use `setLayoutParam` instead of `requestLayout()`.

Comment: not working, I tried using these functions in a different layout and it's working.. I don't know why its not working with a relativelayout that has a recyclerview inside :(